# Changes to NgModel on input not updating view

Tags: angular

I have an input field on my html that I need to limit the value of.

I am trying doing like this:

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let option of options">
    <input type="text" [ngModel]="option.value" (change)="onChangeValue($event.target.value, option)">
</div>
```

Typescript:

```
onChangeValue(valueString: string, option: OptionViewModel) {
    var value: number = parseInt(valueString);

    // Check some conditions. Simplified code just for example
    if (option.value != value && value > 5) {
        value = 5;
    }

    option.value = value;
}
```

OptionViewModel:

```
export class OptionViewModel {
    public optionId: number;
    public description: string;
    public pollId: number;
    public value?: number;
}
```

I tried using two-way binding, but my code relies on the previous value of option.value, and using two-way binding changes the variable before entering the function.

The problem is, sometimes the input field is not being updated.
It looks like I just work the first time the value need to be changed, so for example, if input 6 the field is correctly changed to 5, but then if I add a 0 (making it 50), it doesn't correct to 5.

I debbuged the code and it is running the function and changing the option.value, and even using Augury to inspect the objects show the correct value.

Comment: Does `OptionViewModel` contain several fields? Can you show us that class (if not too large)?

Comment: @ConnorsFan I updated the question with the class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your second edit, the content of the input element is not updated because Angular has not detected any change (`option.value` was 5, and it is still 5). Here are two methods to force the refresh of the element.

---

**Method 1 - Replace the option item in the array**

You can force the field to update by replacing the option in the array with a cloned copy, as shown in **[this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-driven-form-2-nxzhgm?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**:

```
<div *ngFor="let option of options; let i=index">
  <input [ngModel]="option.value" (change)="onChangeValue($event.target.value, i)" type="text" >
</div>
```

```
onChangeValue(valueString: string, index: number) {
  var value: number = parseInt(valueString);
  if (value > 5) {
    value = 5;
  }
  this.options[index] = this.options[index].cloneWithValue(value);
}

export class OptionViewModel {
  public optionId: number;
  public description: string;
  public pollId: number;
  public value?: number;

  public cloneWithValue(value: number): OptionViewModel {
    let dest = new OptionViewModel();
    dest.optionId = this.optionId;
    dest.description = this.description;
    dest.pollId = this.pollId;
    dest.value = value;
    return dest;
  }
}
```

---

**Method 2 - Use an additional field in the trackBy function**

An alternative solution is to add an additional field to `OptionViewModel` (e.g. `lastModified`) and to use it in a `trackBy` method of the `ngFor` directive (see [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-driven-form-2-kqvecm?file=app/app.component.ts)):

```
<div *ngFor="let option of options; trackBy: trackByFn">
  <input [ngModel]="option.value" (change)="onChangeValue($event.target.value, option)" type="text">
</div>
```

```
onChangeValue(valueString: string, option: OptionViewModel) {
  var value: number = parseInt(valueString);
  if (value > 5) {
    value = 5;
  }
  option.value = value;
  option.lastModified = Date.now();
}

trackByFn(index: number, option: OptionViewModel) {
  return `${index}___${option.lastModified}`;
}
```

```
export class OptionViewModel {
  public optionId: number;
  public description: string;
  public pollId: number;
  public value?: number;
  public lastModified: number = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, both solutions worked. Do you know which one is better?

Comment: The first method recreates the `options` items as you edit the values. If you are referencing these objects in other parts of the code, you may not want to clone them. On the other hand, the `trackBy` method looks a little strange to me, but it keeps the option references intact. So, I don't know which one is really better...

Comment: What if option is primitive?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution worked for me is to use [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef).The change detection tree collects all views and updates the values of all components

1. Make variable type of ChangeDetectorRef in contructor like below:-

   ```
    constructor(private changeDet:ChangeDetectorRef) { }
   ```
2. Now just call **changeDet.detectChanges()** after setting/updating your value

   ```
    onChangeValue(valueString: string, option: OptionViewModel) {
    var value: number = parseInt(valueString);

    // Check some conditions. Simplified code just for example
    if (option.value != value && value > 5) {
        value = 5;
    }

    option.value = value;
    this.changeDet.detectChanges();//Detects changes and updates value
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Hi try to change ng model two way binding ,like that

```
    <div *ngFor="let option of options">
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="option.value"  #ctrl="ngModel"
 (change)="onChangeValue($event.target.value, option)">
    </div>
```

Comment: I tried using two-way binding, but my actual code relies on the previous value of option.value. I updated my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Found a simpler workaround. Just use *(keyup)* instead of *(change)*.

```
<input class="editable-field-input" type="number" value="editableFieldValue" [(ngModel)]="editableFieldValue" (keyup)="editableFieldValueChanged()" />
```

I haven't passed the event as argument because I already have the ngModel updating my variable.

```
editableFieldValueChanged() {
  if (this.editableFieldValue < -100) {
    this.editableFieldValue = -100;
  }
  if (this.editableFieldValue > 100) {
    this.editableFieldValue = 100;
  }
}
```

The TLDR version is, Angular considers this the same as choosing the same option in a dropdown over and over again, because the previous and current value is the same and hence it finds no reason to update the DOM element.

I believe this approach works because the *(keyup)* has a different execution order compared to the other events. I will leave the explaining to the people who are a lot more knowledgeable than I am.

Answer (score 0):

You can try also creating a simple observable that will check the information for you.

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<input #inputName type="text" />`,
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  value: string = '';
  @ViewChild('inputName') inputName: ElementRef;

  ngOnInit() {
    const input = this.inputName.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement;
    Observable.fromEvent(input, 'input')
      .map((evt: Event) => evt.target as HTMLInputElement)
      .subscribe(target => target.value = Number(target.value) > 5 ? '5' : target.value);
  }
}
```